# A Bernstein-like Combinatorial Sum

Tags: co.combinatorics

Do sums of the "convoluted Bernstein" form 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m {m\choose j} q^j (1-q)^{m-j}  {n \choose k} \left(\frac j m\right)^k \left(1- \frac j m\right)^{n-k} 
$$
admit closed forms? My attempts to use generating functions have not worked.

Comment: May be try to find recursion for sums in $m$ and then ABC-algorithms?

Answer (score 5):

First off, it is always worth to remove common factors (not depending on the index of summation) from the summands. The given sum is reduced to (I also assume $k>0$ to have summation start from $j=0$):
$$\binom{n}{k} \frac{m!}{m^n}\cdot \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{q^j j^k}{j!}\cdot \frac{(1-q)^{m-j} (m-j)^{n-k}}{(m-j)!}.$$

Notice that $\frac{q^j j^k}{j!}$ is the coefficient of $x^j$ in $\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k e^{qx}$.

Similarly, $\frac{(1-q)^{m-j} (m-j)^{n-k}}{(m-j)!}$ is the coefficient of $x^{m-j}$ in $\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n-k} e^{(1-q)x}$.

Furthermore, it is helpful to know that 
$$\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^t = \sum_{s=0}^t S(t,s)\cdot x^s\cdot \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^s,$$
where $S(t,s)$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html).

Combining, we have that $\frac{q^j j^k}{j!}$ is the coefficient of $x^j$ in $$\sum_{s=0}^k S(k,s)\cdot x^s\cdot q^s\cdot e^{qx} = B_k(qx)\cdot e^{qx},$$
where $B_k(x)$ is [Bell polynomial of first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) (or [Touchard polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials)).

Similarly, $\frac{(1-q)^{m-j} (m-j)^{n-k}}{(m-j)!}$ is the coefficient of $x^{m-j}$ in $B_{n-k}((1-q)x)\cdot e^{(1-q)x}$.

In summary, we have that the original sum (but starting at $j=0$) equals the coefficient of $x^m$ in
$$\binom{n}{k}\cdot \frac{m!}{m^n}\cdot B_k(qx)\cdot B_{n-k}((1-q)x)\cdot e^x.$$

**UPD.** It may be useful to know that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\cdot B_k(qx)\cdot B_{n-k}((1-q)x) = B_n(x).$$

Comment: Hm, maybe that's the expression OP started with...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: I don't think so, since OP's "attempts to use generating functions have not worked". Here I showed how g.f. work in this case.